# $I = [0,1]$ with euclidean topology. $f : I \rightarrow I^2 = I \times I$. If f is surjective then f is not injective

Tags: general-topology

I have this problem which seems trivial, but I do not know how to get to the answer. I have the set $[0,1]$ with the Euclidean topology, and an arbitrary continuous function  $f : I \rightarrow I^2 = I \times I$. I need to prove that if it is surjective then it cannot be injective.

I tried to think to the problem in this way: if $f$ is surjective and also injective, than we would have a homeomorphism between $I$ and $I \times I$.

I wanted to say that one is compact and the other is not to reach a contradiction. However in my opinion they are both compact because product of compacts is compact as well, so I do not see why it would be a problem to have the injective property. Any tips?

Comment: I don't think there is a reasonable notion of 'generic' for which a generic function is surjective. In fact, I believe (but I'm not completely sure)  that a generic function will not be surjective (in the sense that there is an open dense set of such functions). You probably meant to write 'arbitrary'.

Comment: @tomasz Yep, edited!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: rather than compactness, you might want to look at connectedness. Now both $I$ and $I \times I$ are connected, so that doesn't do much. But what happens if you remove a point from each of them?

Answer (score 1):

As I is compact Hausdorf, f is closed map.
Thus were f a bijection, it would be a homeomorphism.
As I and I×I are not homeomorphic, f cannot be bijective.
They are not homeomorphic because I has cut points and IxI does not.
A cut point is a point whose removal will disconnect the space.

Comment: It seems the real question is how to show they are not homeomorphic.  The OP tried "one is compact and the other is not" but that failed, since they are both compact.

Comment: @GEdgar.  See edit.